# Consumable Resource Allocation Graph

Tags: operating-system, deadlock

Can someone help me or direct me a place where I can find an example solution for this?
I know how to draw RAG(resource allocation graph) for reusable resources. But no idea how to draw this consumable RAG..
Thanks.

[image: Question]